Casadi c++ produce different solution that in Python
I have the following problem, which is not the full problem: I need to convert into C++. However, I am getting somewhat different results in C++. It's still unclear why C++ gets a different result than the Python version.
import casadi as ca
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import json 
# Parameters and fixed initial pose
data = np.array([
    [0.0714334, 0.00638967, 1.66001],
    [0.171036, 0.015299, 1.66001],
    [0.270638, 0.0242084, 1.66001],
    [0.37024, 0.0331177, 1.66001],
    [0.469843, 0.0420271, 1.66001],
    [0.569445, 0.0509365, 1.66001],
    [0.669047, 0.0598458, 1.66001],
    [0.76865, 0.0687552, 1.66001],
    [0.868252, 0.0776645, 1.66001],
    [0.967854, 0.0865739, 1.66001],
    [1.06746, 0.0954833, 1.66001],
    [1.16706, 0.104393, 1.66001],
    [1.26666, 0.113302, 1.66001],
    [1.36626, 0.122211, 1.66001],
    [1.46587, 0.131121, 1.66001],
    [1.56547, 0.14003, 1.66001],
    [1.66507, 0.148939, 1.66001],
    [1.76467, 0.157849, 1.66001],
    [1.86428, 0.166758, 1.66001],
    [1.96388, 0.175668, 1.66001],
    [2.06348, 0.184577, 1.66001],
    [2.16308, 3.193486, 1.66001],
    [2.26268, 0.202396, 1.66001],
    [2.36229, 0.211305, 1.66001],
    [2.46189, 3.220214, 1.66001],
    [2.56149, 0.229124, 1.66001],
    [2.66109, 0.238033, 1.66001],
    [2.7607, 0.246942, 1.66001],
    [2.8603, 0.255852, 1.66001],
    [2.9599, 0.264761, 1.66001],
    [3.0595, 0.27367, 1.66001],
    [3.15911, 3.28258, 1.66001],
    [3.25871, 0.291489, 1.66001],
    [3.35831, 0.300399, 1.66001],
    [3.45791, 0.309308, 1.66001],
    [3.55751, 3.318217, 1.66001],
    [3.65712, 0.327127, 1.66001],
    [3.75672, 0.336036, 1.66001],
    [3.85632, 0.444945, 1.66001],
    [3.95592, 0.453855, 1.66001],
    [4.05553, 0.462764, 1.66001],
    [4.15513, 0.471673, 1.66001]
])

A_p = np.array([[-0.0645709, -0.997913], [0.0645709, 0.997913]])
b_p = np.array([0.737278, 0.632449])

x_list = data[:, 0]
y_list = data[:, 1]
theta_list = data[:, 2]  # Sample orientation values

curvature_weight = 1.0
curvature_rate_weight = 1.0
distance_weight = 1.0
v_max = 1.0
delta_t = 0.1
wheelbase = 1.0  # Length of the wheelbase for car-like dynamics
n = len(x_list)

# Initial fixed pose
x0_val = x_list[0]
y0_val = y_list[0]
theta0_val = theta_list[0]

# Define optimization variables for remaining poses, velocities, and steering angles
x = ca.MX.sym('x', n - 1)
y = ca.MX.sym('y', n - 1)
theta = ca.MX.sym('theta', n - 1)
v = ca.MX.sym('v', n - 1)        # Velocity variable for each timestep
delta = ca.MX.sym('delta', n - 1)  # Steering angle for each timestep

# Objective function
objective = 0
# for i in range(n - 3):  # Adjust indices since initial pose is excluded
#     dds_x = x[i+2] - 2 * x[i+1] + x[i]
#     dds_y = y[i+2] - 2 * y[i+1] + y[i]
#     objective += curvature_weight * (dds_x**2 + dds_y**2)
    
# for i in range(n - 4):
#     ddds_x = x[i+3] - 3 * x[i+2] + 3 * x[i+1] - x[i]
#     ddds_y = y[i+3] - 3 * y[i+2] + 3 * y[i+1] - y[i]
#     objective += curvature_rate_weight * (ddds_x**2 + ddds_y**2)

# Add penalty for distance between consecutive points
# for i in range(n - 2):
#     distance_sq = (x[i+1] - x[i])**2 + (y[i+1] - y[i])**2
#     print(distance_sq)
#     objective += distance_weight * distance_sq  # Penalize large distances between consecutive points

# # Constraints
g = []
lb_g = []
ub_g = []


# Kinematic constraints for car-like dynamics
for i in range(n - 2):
    # x_t+1 = x_t + delta_t * v * cos(theta)
    g.append(x[i+1] - (x[i] + delta_t * v[i] * ca.cos(theta[i])))
    # print(x[i+1] - (x[i] + delta_t * v[i] * ca.cos(theta[i])))
    lb_g.append(0)
    ub_g.append(0)
    
    # # y_t+1 = y_t + delta_t * v * sin(theta)
    g.append(y[i+1] - (y[i] + delta_t * v[i] * ca.sin(theta[i])))
    lb_g.append(0)
    ub_g.append(0)
    
    # # theta_t+1 = theta_t + delta_t * v * tan(delta) / L
    g.append(theta[i+1] - (theta[i] + delta_t * v[i] * ca.tan(delta[i]) / wheelbase))
    print("   ", theta[i+1] - (theta[i] + delta_t * v[i] * ca.tan(delta[i]) / wheelbase))
    lb_g.append(0)
    ub_g.append(0)
    


# # Velocity and steering angle constraints
# max_steering_angle = np.deg2rad(25)
max_steering_angle = 0.52
for i in range(n - 1):
    # Velocity constraints
    g.append(v[i])
    lb_g.append(0.0)  # Minimum velocity (no reversing)
    ub_g.append(v_max)  # Maximum velocity
    # Steering angle constraints (example: max steering angle of 30 degrees)
    g.append(delta[i])
    lb_g.append(-max_steering_angle)
    ub_g.append(max_steering_angle)
    

# for i in range(0, n-1):
#     for j in range(0, 2):
#         g.append(x[i]*A_p[j, 0] + y[i]*A_p[j, 1])
#         lb_g.append(-ca.inf)
#         ub_g.append(b_p[j])
        
# Define NLP problem without the fixed initial pose in the variables
nlp = {'x': ca.vertcat(x, y, theta, v, delta), 'f': objective, 'g': ca.vertcat(*g)}

# Set IPOPT solver options
opts = {
    'ipopt.print_level': 5,
    'print_time': False,
    'ipopt.tol': 1e-6,
    'ipopt.max_iter': 1000
}
solver = ca.nlpsol('solver', 'ipopt', nlp, opts)

# Initial guess (excluding the fixed initial pose)
x0_guess = np.hstack((x_list[1:], y_list[1:], theta_list[1:], np.ones(n - 1) * v_max, np.zeros(n - 1)))

print(x0_guess)

# Solve the problem
solution = solver(x0=x0_guess, lbx=-ca.inf, ubx=ca.inf, lbg=lb_g, ubg=ub_g)


problem_data = {
    'variables': nlp['x'].size1(),
    'objective': str(objective),
    'constraints': [str(nlp['g'])],
    'bounds': {
        'lb_vars': -ca.inf,
        'ub_vars': ca.inf,
        'lb_constraints': lb_g,
        'ub_constraints': ub_g,
    }
}

# Write to JSON file
with open("nlp_debug_python.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(problem_data, f, indent=4)

print("NLP problem saved to nlp_debug.json")

# Extract optimized values, adding back fixed initial pose
x_opt = solution['x'][:n - 1]
y_opt = solution['x'][n - 1:2 * (n - 1)]
theta_opt = np.vstack((np.array([[theta0_val]]), solution['x'][2 * (n - 1):]))
v_opt = solution['x'][3 * (n - 1):4 * (n - 1)]
delta_opt = solution['x'][4 * (n - 1):]

# Visualization
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.plot(x_list, y_list, 'bo--', label='Initial Path')
plt.plot(x_opt, y_opt, 'ro-', label='Optimized Path')

# Boundary line plots
x_vals = np.linspace(-5, 5, 400)
y1_vals = (b_p[0] - A_p[0, 0] * x_vals) / A_p[0, 1]
y2_vals = (b_p[1] - A_p[1, 0] * x_vals) / A_p[1, 1]
plt.plot(x_vals, y1_vals, label=r'$-0.368x - 0.929y \leq 2.24$')
plt.plot(x_vals, y2_vals, label=r'$-0.368x - 0.929y \leq 0.87$')

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Here is the C++ version, which gives different results, not quite sure where I made the mistake (
#include <casadi/casadi.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "matplotlibcpp.h"
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using namespace casadi;
using namespace std;
namespace plt = matplotlibcpp;

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
    // Parameters and fixed initial pose
    DM data = DM({
    {0.0714334, 0.00638967, 1.66001},
    {0.171036, 0.015299, 1.66001},
    {0.270638, 0.0242084, 1.66001},
    {0.37024, 0.0331177, 1.66001},
    {0.469843, 0.0420271, 1.66001},
    {0.569445, 0.0509365, 1.66001},
    {0.669047, 0.0598458, 1.66001},
    {0.76865, 0.0687552, 1.66001},
    {0.868252, 0.0776645, 1.66001},
    {0.967854, 0.0865739, 1.66001},
    {1.06746, 0.0954833, 1.66001},
    {1.16706, 0.104393, 1.66001},
    {1.26666, 0.113302, 1.66001},
    {1.36626, 0.122211, 1.66001},
    {1.46587, 0.131121, 1.66001},
    {1.56547, 0.14003, 1.66001},
    {1.66507, 0.148939, 1.66001},
    {1.76467, 0.157849, 1.66001},
    {1.86428, 0.166758, 1.66001},
    {1.96388, 0.175668, 1.66001},
    {2.06348, 0.184577, 1.66001},
    {2.16308, 3.193486, 1.66001},
    {2.26268, 0.202396, 1.66001},
    {2.36229, 0.211305, 1.66001},
    {2.46189, 3.220214, 1.66001},
    {2.56149, 0.229124, 1.66001},
    {2.66109, 0.238033, 1.66001},
    {2.7607, 0.246942, 1.66001},
    {2.8603, 0.255852, 1.66001},
    {2.9599, 0.264761, 1.66001},
    {3.0595, 0.27367, 1.66001},
    {3.15911, 3.28258, 1.66001},
    {3.25871, 0.291489, 1.66001},
    {3.35831, 0.300399, 1.66001},
    {3.45791, 0.309308, 1.66001},
    {3.55751, 3.318217, 1.66001},
    {3.65712, 0.327127, 1.66001},
    {3.75672, 0.336036, 1.66001},
    {3.85632, 0.444945, 1.66001},
    {3.95592, 0.453855, 1.66001},
    {4.05553, 0.462764, 1.66001},
    {4.15513, 0.471673, 1.66001}});

    DM A_p = DM::horzcat({{-0.0645709, 0.0645709}, {-0.997913, 0.997913}});
    DM b_p = DM::vertcat({0.737278, 0.632449});

    vector<double> x_list, y_list, theta_list;
    int n = data.size1();

    std::cout<< " n " << n << " cols " << data.size2() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        x_list.push_back(data(i, 0).scalar());
        y_list.push_back(data(i, 1).scalar());
        theta_list.push_back(data(i, 2).scalar());  // Sample orientation values
        std::cout<< " " << data(i, 0).scalar() << " " << data(i, 1).scalar() << " " << data(i, 2).scalar() << std::endl;
    }

    double curvature_weight = 1.0;
    double curvature_rate_weight = 1.0;
    double distance_weight = 1.0;
    double v_max = 1.0;
    double delta_t = 0.1;
    double wheelbase = 1.0;

    // Initial fixed pose
    double x0_val = x_list[0];
    double y0_val = y_list[0];
    double theta0_val = theta_list[0];

    // Define optimization variables for remaining poses, velocities, and steering angles
    MX x = MX::sym("x", n - 1);
    MX y = MX::sym("y", n - 1);
    MX theta = MX::sym("theta", n - 1);
    MX v = MX::sym("v", n - 1);
    MX delta = MX::sym("delta", n - 1);

    // Objective function
    MX objective = 0.0;
    
    // for (int i = 0; i < n - 3; ++i) {
    //     MX dds_x = x(i+2) - 2 * x(i+1) + x(i);
    //     MX dds_y = y(i+2) - 2 * y(i+1) + y(i);
    //     objective += curvature_weight * (dds_x*dds_x + dds_y*dds_y);
    // }
    
    // for (int i = 0; i < n - 4; ++i) {
    //     MX ddds_x = x(i+3) - 3 * x(i+2) + 3 * x(i+1) - x(i);
    //     MX ddds_y = y(i+3) - 3 * y(i+2) + 3 * y(i+1) - y(i);
    //     objective += curvature_rate_weight * (ddds_x*ddds_x + ddds_y*ddds_y);
    // }

    // Penalty for distance between consecutive points
    // for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
    //     MX distance_sq = MX::pow(x(i+1) - x(i), 2) + MX::pow((y(i+1) - y(i)), 2);
    //     std::cout<< distance_sq << std::endl;
    //     objective += distance_sq;
    // }

    // Constraints
    vector<MX> g;
    vector<double> lb_g, ub_g;

    // Kinematic constraints for car-like dynamics
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 2; ++i) {
        g.push_back(x(i+1) - (x(i) + delta_t * v(i) * cos(theta(i))));
        lb_g.push_back(0.0);
        ub_g.push_back(0.0);

        g.push_back(y(i+1) - (y(i) + delta_t * v(i) * sin(theta(i))));
        lb_g.push_back(0.0);
        ub_g.push_back(0.0);

        g.push_back(theta(i+1) - (theta(i) + delta_t * v(i) * (tan(delta(i)) / wheelbase)));
        lb_g.push_back(0.0);
        ub_g.push_back(0.0);
    }

    // Velocity and steering angle constraints
    double max_steering_angle = M_PI / 6.0;  // 30 degrees in radians
    // double max_steering_angle = 0.1;  // 30 degrees in radians
    std::cout<< " max_steering_angle " << max_steering_angle  << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        g.push_back(v(i));
        lb_g.push_back(0.0);
        ub_g.push_back(v_max);

        g.push_back(delta(i));
        lb_g.push_back(-max_steering_angle);
        ub_g.push_back(max_steering_angle);
    }

    // // Boundary constraints
    // for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
    //     for (int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    //         g.push_back(x(i) * A_p(j, 0) + y(i) * A_p(j, 1));
    //         lb_g.push_back(-casadi::inf);
    //         ub_g.push_back(static_cast<double>(b_p(j).scalar())); // Cast to double
    //     }
    // }



    // Define NLP problem without the fixed initial pose in the variables
    MX nlp_vars = vertcat(x, y, theta, v, delta);

    // std::cout<< " " << vars.size1() << " " << vars.size2() << std::endl;
    // Set up IPOPT solver
    Dict opts;
    opts["ipopt.print_level"] = 5;
    opts["print_time"] = false;
    opts["ipopt.tol"] = 1e-6;
    opts["ipopt.max_iter"] = 1000;
    // opts["ipopt.constr_viol_tol"] = 1e-4;
    
    auto g_cons = vertcat(g);
    MXDict nlp = {{"x", nlp_vars}, {"f", objective}, {"g", g_cons}};
    Function solver = nlpsol("nlpsol", "ipopt", nlp, opts);

    // Initial guess (excluding the fixed initial pose)
    vector<double> x0_guess;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        x0_guess.push_back(x_list[i]);
    } 
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        x0_guess.push_back(y_list[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i){
        x0_guess.push_back(theta_list[i]);
    } 
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        x0_guess.push_back(v_max);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        x0_guess.push_back(0.0);
    }

    vector<double> lbx, ubx;

    std::map<std::string, DM> arg;
    arg["lbg"] = lb_g;
    arg["ubg"] = ub_g;
    arg["lbx"] = -DM::inf(); // Lower bounds
    arg["ubx"] = DM::inf();  // Upper bounds
    arg["x0"] = x0_guess;
    // Solve the problem
    std::map<string, DM> solution = solver(arg);

    // // Extract optimized values
    vector<double> x_opt(solution["x"](Slice(0, n - 1)).nonzeros());
    vector<double> y_opt(solution["x"](Slice(n - 1, 2 * (n - 1))).nonzeros());
    vector<double> theta_opt(solution["x"](Slice(2 * (n - 1), 3 * (n - 1))).nonzeros());
    vector<double> v_opt(solution["x"](Slice(3 * (n - 1), 4 * (n - 1))).nonzeros());
    vector<double> delta_opt(solution["x"](Slice(4 * (n - 1), 5 * (n - 1))).nonzeros());

    cout << "Optimized Path: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < x_opt.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "X: " << x_opt[i] << ", Y: " << y_opt[i] << endl;
    }

    std::vector<double> x_values, y_values;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size1(); ++i) {
        x_values.push_back(static_cast<double>(data(i, 0)));  // First column
        y_values.push_back(static_cast<double>(data(i, 1)));  // Second column
    }

    // Generate x values from -5 to 5, with 400 points
    int num_points = 400;
    std::vector<double> x_vals(num_points);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) {
        x_vals[i] = -5.0 + i * (10.0 / (num_points - 1));  // from -5 to 5
    }

    // Calculate y values for the lines based on A_p and b_p
    std::vector<double> y1_vals(num_points);
    std::vector<double> y2_vals(num_points);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_points; ++i) {
        y1_vals[i] = (static_cast<double>(b_p(0)) -  static_cast<double>(A_p(0, 0)) * x_vals[i]) /  static_cast<double>(A_p(0, 1));
        y2_vals[i] = (static_cast<double>(b_p(1)) -  static_cast<double>(A_p(1, 0)) * x_vals[i]) /  static_cast<double>(A_p(1, 1));
    }

    // Plot the lines with labels
    plt::figure();
    plt::plot(x_vals, y1_vals, "r-");
    plt::plot(x_vals, y2_vals, "b-");
    plt::plot(x_values, y_values, "bo--");  // Blue line with circle markers
    plt::plot(x_opt, y_opt, "ro-");
    plt::legend();
    plt::title("Trajectory Optimization");
    plt::xlabel("X position");
    plt::ylabel("Y position");
    plt::show();

    return 0;
}

Update:
The issue seems to be related to the value of max_steering_angle = np.deg2rad(30) = 0.5235987755982988. When I use 0.52 in both Python and C++, the results match. However, even with 0.5235987755982988, C++ gives the same result. In Python, though, using 0.5235987755982988 produces a different outcome. I suspect this discrepancy may be related to precession, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

What differences do you see? Note that the numbers Pyton and C++ work with aren't the same, the representations may differ.

Print intermediate results and find the first point where you see a difference. You could just be running into ordinary rounding errors though.

@vonbrand I could ping down the issue, but still not clear how to fix it (: check the comment under Update
